# i want to upload video to the firebase storage inside a folder with unique names?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to upload video to the firebase storage inside a folder with unique names.

What i am doing current in my code is, i am trying to record a video and i want to upload it to the firebase storage.

Please review my code and help me with an appropriate answer

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Uri videouri;
    Button button;


    private StorageReference videoRef;
    private DatabaseReference ref;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videoRef= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("videos");
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("videos");


      VideoView videoView=findViewById(R.id.videoView);
      button=findViewById(R.id.button3);
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              upload();
              Double abc=Math.random();
              Log.i("info", "onCreate: "+abc);
              String filename="video";
              StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
              videoRef =storageRef.child("/videos"+"/"+videouri+".mp4");
          }
      });
    }
    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
        ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
    }

    public void upload() {
    if (videouri != null) {
     final UploadTask uploadTask = videoRef.putFile(videouri);
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success on upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    updateProgress(taskSnapshot);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing to Upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void updateProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

        long fileSize = taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();

        long UploadBytes = taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred();
        long progress = (100 * UploadBytes) / fileSize;
        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbar);
        progressBar.setProgress((int) progress);


    }

    public void record(View view) {


        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       videouri=data.getData();
       if(resultCode==1){
       Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n"+videouri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }else if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED){
    Toast.makeText(this, "RECORDING CANCELLED.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
    //  Toast.makeText(this, "failed to record", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n"+videouri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

    }

}
```

Comment: what is problem with current code ?

Comment: @Ashish the current code upload video to firebase but not in a folder and when i upload another video it overrides the previous video

Comment: is your video uri same all time ?

Comment: no it is different

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `videoRef` **after** you start to upload the video, which means the value is never user.

The simplest way to fix it is with something like this:

```
public void upload() {
  if (videouri != null) {
    String filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString;
    videoRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("videos")
                              .child("videos").child(filename+".mp4");
    final UploadTask uploadTask = videoRef.putFile(videouri);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
      ...
```

The above will generate a unique filename every time you upload a file.

---

An alternative for the file name can be to base it on the current timestamp:

```
String filename = System.currentTimeMillis().toString;
```

This typically makes it easier to find new files, as they'll be at the bottom of the list. It has a small chance of not being unique, but it's not very likely in early stages.

---

Another alternative for the file name is to base it on the file that was selected. But in that case, uploading the same source file will end up overwriting the data on the same location on the server.